# Running SVN commands from PHP using exec, shell_exec, or system

Tags: php, svn

I have a very simple piece of code which should theoretically get me a svn list from php

```
<?php
print_r("Method 1<br/>");
$x = exec("/usr/bin/svn list svn+ssh://svn.server.com/path/to/trunk/ 2>&1", $o, $m);
print_r($o);

print_r("<br/><br/><br/>");

print_r("Method 2<br/>");
$x = exec("/usr/bin/svn list --username user --password pass svn+ssh://svn.server.com/path/to/trunk/ 2>&1", $o, $m);
print_r($o);
?>
```

Both these methods return following errors

```
Method 1
Array ( [0] => svn: warning: Can't open file '/root/.subversion/servers': Permission denied [1] => No protocol specified [2] => [3] => (gnome-ssh-askpass:6062): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0 [4] => svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file. [5] => svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly ) 


Method 2
Array ( [0] => svn: warning: Can't open file '/root/.subversion/servers': Permission denied [1] => No protocol specified [2] => [3] => (gnome-ssh-askpass:6062): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0 [4] => svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file. [5] => svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly [6] => svn: warning: Can't open file '/root/.subversion/servers': Permission denied [7] => No protocol specified [8] => [9] => (gnome-ssh-askpass:6066): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0 [10] => svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file. [11] => svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly )
```

I am able to run either of the svn commands from command line just fine, I also have ssh-key based authentication setup to talk to the svn.server.com

All I want to do is get a list of folders from the trunk. our svn is only setup for svn+ssh access.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have a feeling that the php script executes the svn command as the user 'apache', who, I think does not have privilege to access the file /root/.subversion/servers. To verify my point you could test "whoami" command to check the user.

Comment: Though your way is simple, why not use PHP's [`svn`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php) functions? You could get the list with `print_r(svn_ls('svn+ssh://svn.server.com/path/to/trunk/'))`

Comment: @CoderaPurpa I think you're right, any suggestions on how I can get around that? I tried setting /root/.subversion/servers to chmod 777, but not difference.

Comment: @newfurniturey, I need to install svn extension through pear. Let me do that and I will certainly get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is here:

[Calling an svn update from a php script via a browser is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947843/calling-an-svn-update-from-a-php-script-via-a-browser-is-not-working)

1. run a chmod 777 on .svn directory
2. run an svn update via command line
3. call script