# Get svn revision number from external server

Tags: php, svn

Is there a way to access to the url where the svn is installed to get the revision number from an external php:

```
<?php
    $url="the url where the svn is installed";
    $Revisionsvn=(some command to get the revision number through the url);
    echo($Revisionsvn);
?>
```

I have tried

```
<?php
$url = 'your repository here';
$output = `svn info $url`;
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the below command:

```
svn info http://SVN_PATH_TO_REPO
```

What does it return to you?

Check also if the link below could help:
[Running SVN commands from PHP using exec, shell_exec, or system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040859/running-svn-commands-from-php-using-exec-shell-exec-or-system)

Comment: It returns nothing,I´m executing the php from my localhost,and the svn is on a server