# SVN update using php script

Tags: php, linux, svn, shell

I've dogged around but no luck - I have a PHP script containing:

```
echo shell_exec('2>&1 svn update /var/www/html/myProject/');
```

when i run using php from command line it works fine:

```
/usr/bin/php update.php
```

when i try to update it using wget:

```
wget -qO- http://www.DOMAIN.com/update.php
```

I get certification error and svn messages.
I'm pretty sure it's got something to do with Linux user permissions, but cant find what.
Thanks

Comment: Hope this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947843/calling-an-svn-update-from-a-php-script-via-a-browser-is-not-working

Comment: not so much...i read it before posting.

Answer (score 0):

how do you run from the console, then run svn user is logged in, if you run up a browser, the user is from web server, check whether the user has access to the svn comman and directory.

If that does not work, and you have Linux, you do this:

```
sudo su -
```

or

```
su -
su [user_of_www_server] -
/usr/bin/php update.php
```

Then see what happens.

Also, try to specify the full path to svn command, the web server user can not access the appropriate environment variables.